# How do I insert text at the beginning of a vim file using the .vimrc file?

Tags: vim

Recently I've been using vim to write C++ programs.

This is the piece of code that I always add to the file I create.

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

It's getting a little annoying for me to write this each time, specially because I use it on a daily basis.

Is there any way I can automatize this using the .vimrc file?

Comment: You might find better help if you post this to http://vi.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: I'd suggest that you keep this code in a text file, and then when you want to write a new program, duplicate the file, rename it as your new program file, and edit that.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that

Comment: @KevinW. As a matter of fact, this answer has already been answered plenty of times here, long before vi.SE came to existence. Just search for `[vim] template`. There is the manual solution (from the help) that Jens gave, and there are the plugin solutions see http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion or http://vim-wiki.mawercer.de/wiki/topic/text-snippets-skeletons-templates.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your `.vimrc`:

```
" If the file is new, load a template if we have one,
" delete the extra newline at EOF and place cursor on line 1.
autocmd BufNewFile * silent! 0r $HOME/.vim/templates/%:e.tpl
autocmd BufNewFile * $d
autocmd BufNewFile * 1
```

Then create a template file named `.vim/templates/cpp.tpl` with your desired template for C++ files. You can also create a `c.tpl` for C, `pl.tpl` for perl files ending in `.pl` and so on just by placing a file in the `templates` directory.

Whenever a *new* file with one of those extensions is opened, vim loads the template file.